# MVC 4: User.IsInRole() returns false after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC web is acting weird. When I login for the first time, the User.IsInRole("Admin") is returning true and everything works as expected.

But after I login and logout, when i try to login again, the User.IsInRole("Admin") always returns false. But this problem fixed after I tried to login again.

This is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    string redirectUrl = returnUrl;
    string userName = model.UserName;
    UserProfile user = dbAccount.UserProfiles.Where(m => m.Email.Equals(userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (user != null)
    {
        userName = user.UserName;
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(userName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        if (redirectUrl == null)
        {
            redirectUrl = User.IsInRole("Admin") ? "/Admin" : "/";
        }
        return RedirectToLocal(redirectUrl);
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");         
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    Roles.DeleteCookie();
    return RedirectToAction("Home", "Page");
}
```

Somehow after I logout, and login, the WebSecurity.Login() not giving me the correct user role.

Comment: "When I login for the first time, the User.IsInRole("Admin") is returning true" - I don't believe this: I suspect redirectUrl is non-null, and therefore that you aren't calling User.IsInRole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `User.IsInRole()` method gets the roles from  authentication token that is serilaized in the authentication cookie. In your login action the cookie is not parsed yet so `User.IsInRole()` will always return false.

**Why it works on the first login:**
My assumption that on the first login your user already logged in (the cookie is there) and this is why `User.IsInRole("Admin")` returns true. In order to test it before login (when you are on login page) clear all browser cookies and try to login - I assume that you'll get that `User.IsInRole("Admin")` is false.

**But after I login and logout, when i try to login again, the User.IsInRole("Admin") always returns false:** 
When you logout, you delete the authentication cookie, so in Login action the cookie is not there and this is the reason that `User.IsInRole("Admin")` is false.

Since this cookie will be parsed on the request that follows login you can do something like that:

**UPDATED**

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    string redirectUrl = returnUrl;
    string userName = model.UserName;
    UserProfile user = dbAccount.UserProfiles.Where(m => m.Email.Equals(userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (user != null)
    {
        userName = user.UserName;
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(userName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return  this.RedirectToAction("AdminRedirect","Account", new {redirectUrl = redirectUrl});           
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");         
    return View(model);
}


public ActionResult AdminRedirect(string redirectUrl)
{
     if (redirectUrl == null)
     {
           redirectUrl = User.IsInRole("Admin") ? "/Admin" : "/";
     }
     return this.RedirectToLocal(redirectUrl);
 }
```

This way the user roles are checked after redirect so inside `AdminRedirect` action authentication cookie will already be parsed and user roles will be updated.

Comment: It does not work. Nothing has changed, the code still doing the same as my problem. Somehow WebSecurity.Login() is not doing what it suppose to. After logout, the login function does not update User.IsInRole to Admin

Comment: Alex, I realize that after logout and login again, the User.Identity is empty. This is weird because the WebSecurity.Login(userName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe) returns true which means the login is successful, but User.Identity is empty. What could have gone wrong in here?

Comment: As I said User.Identity filled from authentication cookie. WebSecurity.Login() sets this cookie but doesn't parse it, this is the reason that User.Identity is empty.

Comment: I realized that i had an issue in the code so I updated it. Notice that Login returns `this.RedirectToAction("AdminRedirect","Account", new {redirectUrl = redirectUrl});` and there is a new action called `AdminRedirect`in the same `Account` controller. The previus code didn't return the actual redirect to client so this is the reason that it didn't work

Comment: I see now, the cookie was not parsed before the next request after login right? So to parse the cookie, we need to make a request which is RedirectToAction(), thats when we can use User.IsInRole(). Thanks!

Comment: You got it! I am glad I could help.